# How to read users using username in ADB2C?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

How do I define a technical profile with operation "read" using username? I tried input type as "signInNames.userName", "signInNames.username" - but the adb2c page directly throwns an exception error without a ADB2C code.

This is how I defined the signInNames.userName claimtype. Is this to be blamed?

```
   <ClaimType Id="signInNames.userName">
    <DisplayName>Sign in name</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserHelpText/>
    <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
  </ClaimType>
```

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingUsername">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.userName" Required="true" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>

    <!-- Optional claims -->
    <!-- <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.userName" /> -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```